# FRS Failed sysvolcheck on all domain controllers

Tags: active-directory, replication, dfs-r, sysvol

```
Dcdiag /e /test:sysvolcheck /test:advertising
repadmin /replsum 
repadmin /showrepl 
repadmin /bridgeheads
dcdiag /v
```

I found a guide to transition from FRS to DFSR because its more efficient. 
The guide asks you to ensure that your domain is replicating effectively beforehand. I ran all of these commands but on the `Dcdiag /e /test:sysvolcheck /test:advertising`command I get these results:

```
    Doing primary tests

   Testing server: LSITE\LAD001
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... LAD001 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... LAD001 failed test SysVolCheck

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\C1AD001
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... C1AD001 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... C1AD001 passed test SysVolCheck

   Testing server: CSITE\COAD002
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... COAD002 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... COAD002 failed test SysVolCheck

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\C1AD002
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... C1AD002 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... C1AD002 failed test SysVolCheck

   Testing server: LSITE\LAD002
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... LAD002 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... LAD002 failed test SysVolCheck

   Testing server: CSITE\COAD001
      Starting test: Advertising
         ......................... COAD001 passed test Advertising
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... COAD001 failed test SysVolCheck`
```

Basically, the only test it passes is the localhost test. All others fail. Why is this happening and how can I fix it so I can transition to DFSR

Comment: Try looking at the "File Replication Service" event log on the failed targets. Add "/V" to your DCDIAG invocation for verbose messages.

Comment: Starting test: SysVolCheck
         * The File Replication Service SYSVOL ready test
         The registry lookup failed to determine the state of the SYSVOL.  The
         error returned  was 0x5 "Access is denied.".  Check the FRS event log
         to see if the SYSVOL has successfully been shared.
         ......................... C1AD002 failed test SysVolCheck

Comment: @Craig620 thats the output i get from /V on that test.

Comment: Would have been good to mention "0x5 Access is denied" in original post. Are you doing this work with a Domain Admin account? Any errors in the FRS event logs?

Comment: Yes this is all from my domain admin account. I cant see any event logs for FRS

Comment: Did you run this from an elevated cmd/powershell window? As not doing so will give you "Access Denied" type errors.

Comment: Let me try again but i am pretty sure it was on my domain admin running the cmd as admin

Comment: @codedbeard I ran it again this morning and they all passed. I am really confused. I didnt change anything

Comment: I am guessing it wasnt an elevated prompt because doing this test from my non elevated account fails. Elevated account passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular instance was solved by running the test from an elevated command prompt(domain admin plus running cmd as admin)